# Javascript textbox autocomplete clears drop down selection

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

Morning folks.

Novice Rich here once again requesting assistance.

I have just started dabbling with javascript and although I have set up a few onclick/change for setting the focus of radio buttons,that's pretty much my limit.

In my c# code behind, I would like to have an 'onchange' function whereby once a client starts to type in my autocomplete textbox, a drop down list (which is likely to have been populated previously) is reset/cleared to it's original state.

Anyone got any ideas how to do this?

(Chances are I haven't exp[lained myself very well here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want here is to start exploring [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). When you find yourself familiar with it, create a server-side [ASP.NET Handler](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/308001) that returns [JSON](http://www.json.org/) data to your [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) call and from that, populate your autocomplete textbox.

Or, you can of course not reinvent the wheel and just use one of the plethora of [jQuery Auto-Complete plug-ins](http://www.google.no/search?q=jquery+autocomplete) available out there. Whether you'd still need the server-side handler to provide the auto-complete plugin with data depends on your use-case, but in most cases you'd get much better performance out of pre-populating the data when the page loads.